# Marshmallow (API Level 23) Firebase messaging is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I have been trying to implement Firebase messaging in my app for a while now. I have followed different kinds of tutorial, including the official one by Firebase, adding it both manually and automatic with Firebase Assistant.

For some reason, the following statements are true:

- onTokenRefresh() in the class extending FirebaseInstanceIdService, is
  NEVER called.
- onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) in the
  class extending FirebaseInstanceIdService, is NEVER called.
- No messages are received on

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService:**

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService() {

    val TAG = javaClass?.simpleName

    override fun onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh()
        val refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token
        System.out.println("firebasedebug (" + TAG + "): onTokenRefresh(): " + refreshedToken)
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
class : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    val TAG = javaClass?.simpleName

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        System.out.println("firebasedebug (" + TAG + "): onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: " + remoteMessage+")")
    }
}
```

I have added the following to my Manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

<service
    android:name="dk.myapp.service.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="dk.myapp.service.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

(Note that I have tried setting exported to true and false and also with and without the metatag for setting the channel)

I have also added the following to my Application class:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Apparently this was required when I tried to use the method "getToken()" through Firebase. A have also tried with and without these methods.

In my main activity I have tried placing the "getToken()" method through Firebase to attempt to trigger the initialization of the token, but still without any luck.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token
```

I have of course added the messaging library (and google play service modules) to my app module gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
```

An also added this line to the bottom of the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And these to my project gradle:

```
   buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.2'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // google-services plugin
        ...
    }
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
            targetCompatibility = "1.7"
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have of course also added the google-services.json to the project

When sending the messages through the Firebase dashboard I have tried:
 - Entering the channel 
 - Setting target as User segment
 - Setting target as Single device (the token from the app)
 - ...

I have also tried things like:
 - uninstalling and reinstalling the app whenever I tried a new approach
 - deleting instanceid and calling getToken again
 - Trying in both debug and non-debug mode
 - ...

Here is how my list of send messages looks like in the dashboard:

[image]

If any more details are needed, please let me know and I will of course supply them (if possible).

**EDIT**
I tried out the REST API and made some observations.

- First time I tried sending a standard notification I got a response with success: 1 and failure: 0, but the other way around afterward (failure: 1) with "error": "NotRegistered" (see the image below)

[image]

- I get a 200 back every time.
- If I uninstall/reinstall the app and use the new token, the same things as described above, happends again.
- None of of the attempts gave me a visible push message on the device, nor did onMessageReceived method get called, which I have tested through log messages and syso's in the code and with the debugger.

Comment: Have you added the google-services.json file to your project?

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the question, but yes I have :)

Comment: What's the version of google play services that you have included in app level build.gradle file? Can you post that file too?

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as last item in your module `build.gradle`

Comment: @KashishMalhotra Yes of course. I have added the play services to the question (version 15.0.0). I assume this is what you meant?

Comment: @Christopher Yes I have. I'll add that to the question as well

Comment: `getToken()` itself returns null too? Have you tried using the REST API to send the message as well?

Comment: getToken() returns a correct token actually (seems like it). However, when I try to send a push from firebase to this token, the console shows this message afterwards: Invalid registration token. Check the token format

Comment: @AL And no I actually haven't tried the REST API, but I will try it out of course. I haven't thought about that at all. But why do you think it will make a difference (just curious)?

Comment: Using the Firebase Console sends a `notification` message payload. If you're gonna use the REST API, you could try sending a `notification`-only and a `data`-only message payloads. If somehow, the `notification`-only message payload works using the REST API, then the issue might be with the Firebase Console, if not, it's something else.

Comment: @AL. Okay, I tried out the REST API and made some observations. First time I tried sending a standard notification I got a response with success: 1 and failure: 0, but the other way around afterward (failure: 1) with "error": "NotRegistered". I get a 200 back every time though. If I uninstall/reinstall the app and use the new token, the same things happends again. None of of the attempts gave me a visible push message on the device, nor did onMessageReceived method get called (tried to log, syso and debug to test it). Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks a lot so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my particular situation.

The solution for me was to remove the following lines from my manifest file in the application tag:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
tools:node="replace"
tools:replace="android:icon,android:label"
```

Comment: If you remove `android:label`, how will you set the name of the app then?